# How to get JSON on browser from Yarn rest API?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I want to get all the jobs from hadoop resource manager, so I tried with the yarn rest API, but this is returning XML in browser, so is there any way to get the JSON from it?

URL I am hitting is given below:
 server:port/ws/v1/cluster/apps

Comment: Try to add Accept header like this `Accept : application/json`

Comment: just parse the xml if you can't get json from it? would take you less time than it would asking this question

Comment: @MRSrinivas but we can't send those from browser, could we?

Comment: @AmanTandon Why would you want to manually browse to it with a browser and see the output/parse it from there? Write a program, use it to send an extra header, check the response. if application/json worked and you get back json, then you win. Yet, you asked the question here again. Do you want to do this manually? or just write basic 5 lines of code to see if advice given will work and then automate after the poc?

Comment: @zerohero see my point is if JSON is not available then it should it's light weight and render fastly. I already wrote down the code. All I want to know if it is available and I don't know it then I can get the idea from here.. btw thanks for advice

Comment: @AmanTandon: What is the Hadoop version? I could see 2.7.3 by default return JSON response as per codebase.

Comment: @mrsrinivas I am using 2.6 along with cdh 5.5. If it is available in 2.7 then it's cool thanks for the update

Answer (score 3):

As MR Srinivas suggested, the Accept: Application/json does do what you want. Here is an example:

```
Seans-MacBook-Pro:~% wget -qO- --header="Accept: Application/json" http://amarillo-rm.pepperdata.com:8088/ws/v1/cluster/info


{
  "clusterInfo": {
    "id": 1479097299577,
    "startedOn": 1479097299577,
    "state": "STARTED",
    "haState": "ACTIVE",
    "rmStateStoreName": "org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.NullRMStateStore",
    "resourceManagerVersion": "2.6.0-cdh5.5.1",
    "resourceManagerBuildVersion": "2.6.0-cdh5.5.1 from e1581abbb6ab62b0a41b7ce6141d7280bf0c53da by jenkins source checksum db52b8a74b1a7e55c309ec5fbcd7ca",
    "resourceManagerVersionBuiltOn": "2015-12-02T18:44Z",
    "hadoopVersion": "2.6.0-cdh5.5.1",
    "hadoopBuildVersion": "2.6.0-cdh5.5.1 from e1581abbb6ab62b0a41b7ce6141d7280bf0c53da by jenkins source checksum 98e07176d1787150a6a9c087627562c",
    "hadoopVersionBuiltOn": "2015-12-02T18:38Z"
  }
}
```

Comment: I knew this, I want JSON to be returned from browser itself

Comment: the answer is: "you must configure the browser HTTP request header".